Extent Report is not Generating when I run the test in GitHub Actions
I'm using Selenium, SpecFlow, and C#
Locally when I run my automation test, the extent report is generating successfully together with the screenshots.
private static string dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
private static string testResultPath = dir.Replace("\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0", "\\test-output");

public static void ExtentReportInit()
{
    var _htmlReport = new ExtentSparkReporter(@testResultPath + "index.html");
    _htmlReport.Config.ReportName = "Automation Status Report";
    _htmlReport.Config.DocumentTitle = "Automation Status Report";
    _htmlReport.Config.Theme = Theme.Standard;

    _extentReports = new ExtentReports();
    _extentReports.AttachReporter(_htmlReport);
}

However, when I'm running it in GitHub Actions the report is not generating, but the screenshot is generating and uploading.
private static string testResultPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GITHUB_WORKSPACE")!, "test-output");

public static void ExtentReportInit()
{
    var _htmlReport = new ExtentSparkReporter(@testResultPath + "index.html");
    _htmlReport.Config.ReportName = "Automation Status Report";
    _htmlReport.Config.DocumentTitle = "Automation Status Report";
    _htmlReport.Config.Theme = Theme.Standard;

    _extentReports = new ExtentReports();
    _extentReports.AttachReporter(_htmlReport);
}

Here is my github actions for reference
# ... bunch of code before these codes ...

    - name: Create report directory
      run: mkdir -p ${{github.workspace}}/test-output

    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test projectName.csproj --configuration Release
    
    - name: Upload Report
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      if: always()
      with:
        name: test-results
        path: ${{github.workspace}}/test-output

base on my investigations and tried different solutions, the main issue here is i cannot generate the html file only.
